# Names of the PowerPivot tables do not update in PivotTable

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, powerpivot

I have imported an Excel table into PowerPivot and renamed the tab in the PowerPivot tab. However, when I create a PivotTable in the Excel sheet, I can only see "Table1", etc. instead of the name I have given in the PowerPivot tab.

I have tried clicking Update All, changed Update Mode to automatic, however, the table name in the PivotTable still does not update. On the Linked Table tab, it says Excel Table: Table1 on the top but there doesn't seem to be any option, how I could change the name to correspond to new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is to modify:

**Formulas >> Name Manager >> Edit name** in the linked table field

This then updates the table in the PowerPivot view, which also manifests as a change in Pivot Tables generated from PowerPivot.